# google sheets onedit specific cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

In google sheets, I'm looking to have data copied from one sheet to another after editing a particular cell in the sheet being copied. I have code that does what I want except for only being trigger by the particular cell. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

```
function OnEdit(e) {


 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1P6gj2UwfRmSMYZ4LBovvqbqy88aluOysPqWWhWbw_VE") 
 var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Submit");
 var destination_sheet = destination.getSheetByName("Point Tracker");
 var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A2:C2"); 
 var editedcell = source_sheet.getRange("C2"); 


 if(editedcell.getValue() !== 0){   

 var last_row = destination_sheet.getLastRow();
 destination_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
 var destination_range = destination_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":C"+(last_row+1));
 source_range.copyTo(destination_range,{contentsOnly:true}); 
 source_sheet.getRange("C2").setValue("");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if this works

```
function onEdit(e) {

if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "Submit" || 
    e.range.getA1Notation() != 'C2' || typeof e.value == 'object') return;
SpreadsheetApp.openById("1P6gj2UwfRmSMYZ4LBovvqbqy88aluOysPqWWhWbw_VE")
  .getSheetByName('Point Tracker')
  .appendRow(e.range.offset(0, -2, 1, 3)
  .getValues()[0]);
e.range.setValue(null);
}
```

Note: this script uses an event object. Don't test the script by clikcing the play button in the script editor. Instead edit the acual cell and see if it works.

Comment: Most welcome @jc247. Please accept the answer or upvote if that answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work.  I usually have to debug these things but hopefully I got you closer.

```
function copyOnTrigger(e) 
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1P6gj2UwfRmSMYZ4LBovvqbqy88aluOysPqWWhWbw_VE") 
 var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Submit");
 var destination_sheet = destination.getSheetByName("Point Tracker");
 var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A2:C2"); 
 var editedcell = source_sheet.getRange("C2"); 
 var cell=e.range.getCell(1,1).getA1Notation();


 if(cell=='C2' && e.value != 0){   

 var last_row = destination_sheet.getLastRow();
 destination_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
 var destination_range = destination_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":C"+(last_row+1));
 source_range.copyTo(destination_range,{contentsOnly:true}); 
 source_sheet.getRange("C2").setValue("");

  }
}
```